# DIalogPreference Problem

Tags: android

I am using preferences, and this snippet of XML always causes my application to stop unexpectly when I hit a menu settings button which is supposed to display a list of preferences. I can use CheckBoxPreference and ListPreference successfully but I cannot use DialogPreference. I cannot seem to find an example XML snippet anywhere.

I need this dialog to collect a phone number in a string.

Comment: The snippet  <DialogPreference
  android:key="NUMB"
  android:dialogIcon="@drawable/icon"
  android:title="Phone Number"
  android:summary="The phone number of your child"
  android:dialogTitle="Phone Number"
  android:dialogMessage="Phone Number Message"
  android:negativeButtonText="@null"
  android:positiveButtonText="@null"
  android:defaultValue=""
 />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have been using EditTextPreference which extends DialogPreference. This works.

Comment: DialogPreference is an abstract class and therefore you must extend if before you can use it.